# java factory pattern question

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

I'm currently using my factory like this:

```
public class AbstractFactory
{
    public static AbstractHeader parseHeader(File file)
    {
            if(AFactory.canRead(file))return AFactory.parseHeader(file);
            if(BFactory.canRead(file))return BFactory.parseHeader(file);

            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("File ["+file+"] not supported");
    }

    public static AbstractContent parseContent(AbstractHeader h)
    {
            if(h instanceof AHeader){
                    return AFactory.parseContent((AHeader) h);
            }
            if(h instanceof BHeader){
                    return BFactory.parseContent((BHeader) h);
            }
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Header not supported");
    }
}
```

the parseHeader() will return an instance of either AHeader or BHeader, and in a later time will ask for the AbstractContent. Is there a better way to do this ? Get away with the instanceof checks ?

Comment: +1 to Darron's answer. Also, a matter of style: AbstractFactory is not abstract, so the name is misleading.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following code to your existing classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractHeader {
    abstract AbstractContent parseContent();
}

public class AHeader extends AbstractHeader {
    public AbstractContent parseContent() {
         return AFactory.parseContent((AHeader) h);
    }
}

public class BHeader extends AbstractHeader {
    public AbstractContent parseContent() {
         return BFactory.parseContent((AHeader) h);
    }
}
```

Now you can just call h.parseContent().  This is called polymorphism.

Comment: +1 Nice and clean solution. Makes extending the class very easy.

Comment: off-course ! I was so blind with the factory idea that I didn't even thought of the simpler solution !